# Why first line `import jQuery from "../core.js";` is included in `load.js` even though it is already included in `jquery.js`

Tags: javascript, jquery, import, export, es6-modules

I was just going through jQuery's source code. But then I came across the [following file](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/main/src/ajax/load.js):

### [load.js](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/main/src/ajax/load.js)

```js
import jQuery from "../core.js";
import stripAndCollapse from "../core/stripAndCollapse.js";

import "../core/parseHTML.js";
import "../ajax.js";
import "../traversing.js";
import "../manipulation.js";
import "../selector.js";

/**
 * Load a url into a page
 */
jQuery.fn.load = function( url, params, callback ) {
    var selector, type, response,
        self = this,
        off = url.indexOf( " " );

    if ( off > -1 ) {
        selector = stripAndCollapse( url.slice( off ) );
        url = url.slice( 0, off );
    }

    // If it's a function
    if ( typeof params === "function" ) {

        // We assume that it's the callback
        callback = params;
        params = undefined;

    // Otherwise, build a param string
    } else if ( params && typeof params === "object" ) {
        type = "POST";
    }

    // If we have elements to modify, make the request
    if ( self.length > 0 ) {
        jQuery.ajax( {
            url: url,

            // If "type" variable is undefined, then "GET" method will be used.
            // Make value of this field explicit since
            // user can override it through ajaxSetup method
            type: type || "GET",
            dataType: "html",
            data: params
        } ).done( function( responseText ) {

            // Save response for use in complete callback
            response = arguments;

            self.html( selector ?

                // If a selector was specified, locate the right elements in a dummy div
                // Exclude scripts to avoid IE 'Permission Denied' errors
                jQuery( "<div>" ).append( jQuery.parseHTML( responseText ) ).find( selector ) :

                // Otherwise use the full result
                responseText );

        // If the request succeeds, this function gets "data", "status", "jqXHR"
        // but they are ignored because response was set above.
        // If it fails, this function gets "jqXHR", "status", "error"
        } ).always( callback && function( jqXHR, status ) {
            self.each( function() {
                callback.apply( this, response || [ jqXHR.responseText, status, jqXHR ] );
            } );
        } );
    }

    return this;
};
```

### [jquery.js](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/main/src/jquery.js)

```js
import jQuery from "./core.js";

import "./selector.js";
import "./traversing.js";
import "./callbacks.js";
import "./deferred.js";
import "./deferred/exceptionHook.js";
import "./core/ready.js";
import "./data.js";
import "./queue.js";
import "./queue/delay.js";
import "./attributes.js";
import "./event.js";
import "./event/trigger.js";
import "./manipulation.js";
import "./manipulation/_evalUrl.js";
import "./wrap.js";
import "./css.js";
import "./css/hiddenVisibleSelectors.js";
import "./css/showHide.js";
import "./serialize.js";
import "./ajax.js";
import "./ajax/xhr.js";
import "./ajax/script.js";
import "./ajax/jsonp.js";
import "./ajax/load.js";
import "./core/parseXML.js";
import "./core/parseHTML.js";
import "./effects.js";
import "./effects/animatedSelector.js";
import "./offset.js";
import "./dimensions.js";
import "./deprecated.js";
import "./exports/amd.js";
import "./exports/global.js";

export default jQuery;
```

I understand that the file `load.js` is being imported to `jquery.js` for its side-effects only and `load.js` doesn't export anything. But what I didn't understand is that why first line `import jQuery from "../core.js";` is included in `load.js` even though it is already included in `jquery.js`. If `jquery.js` already imports both `core.js` and `load.js` then why does `load.js` also have to import the same `core.js`?

*If this question isn't appropriate here, please migrate this to another appropriate place.*